# Find the Largest number in the first column of Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
int [ ][ ] matrix = {{ 10, 23, 93, 44 },{ 22, 34, 25, 3 },{ 84, 11, 7, 52 }};
```

and I want to find the max value on the first column of this array which is 84

This is my whole code which give me the max value of each column in this array

```
     public class Sample {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {

int[][] matrix = {{10, 23, 93, 44}, {22, 34, 25, 3}, {84, 11, 7, 52}};

int[] max = matrix[0];

for (int row = 1; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix[0].length; column++) {
        
        if (matrix[row][column] > max[column]) {
            
            max[column] = matrix[row][column];
        }
    }
}
for (int number : max) {
    System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
}}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So you are already creating an array with the max number of each column. What's stopping you from just getting the very first value? eG `System.out.println("Max for column 1: " + max[0]);` - You already seem to have the solution

Comment: find the max value on the first column of this array which is 84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] matrix = {{10, 23, 93, 44}, {22, 34, 25, 3}, {84, 11, 7, 52}};

  int max = matrix[0][0];
  for (int row = 1; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    if (max < matrix[row][0]) {
      max = matrix[row][0];
    }
  }
  System.out.println(max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum value of only one column needs to be found, then no nested loop is needed:

```java
static int maxOfFirstColumn(int[][] arr) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int[] row : arr) {
        if (null != row && row.length > 0) {
            max = Math.max(max, row[0]);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

---

Solution using Stream API:

```java
static int maxOfFirstColumn(int[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr) // Stream<int[]>
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(row -> row.length > 0)
        .mapToInt(row -> row[0]) // IntStream
        .max()
        .getAsInt();
}
```